# How can I sort Nodes in TreeView (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I want to sort elements in Spreadsheets and elements in Documents in the TreeView component (WindowsForms). Is it possible?

[image]

I have read that article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

but I still don't know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
private TreeView treeView1;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
    this.Text = "Form1";

    treeView1 = new TreeView();
    treeView1.Size = new Size(200, 200);

    TreeNode docNode = new TreeNode("Documents");
    TreeNode spreadSheetNode = new TreeNode("Spreadsheets");

    // Add some additional nodes.
    spreadSheetNode.Nodes.Add("payroll.xls");
    spreadSheetNode.Nodes.Add("checking.xls");
    spreadSheetNode.Nodes.Add("tracking.xls");
    docNode.Nodes.Add("phoneList.doc");
    docNode.Nodes.Add("resume.doc");

    // Add the root nodes to the TreeView.
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(spreadSheetNode);
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(docNode);

    // Sort
    treeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = new NodeSorter();

    Controls.Add(treeView1);
}

public class NodeSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        TreeNode tx = x as TreeNode;
        TreeNode ty = y as TreeNode;

        if (tx.Text.Length != ty.Text.Length)
            return tx.Text.Length - ty.Text.Length;

        return string.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: [TreeView.Sort() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.sort)

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = treeView1.Nodes[0];
var list = node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();

node.Nodes.Clear();
foreach (var sorted in list)
{
    node.Nodes.Add(sorted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NodeSorter` class firts check the length of the node text and compare the items based on their length and only when the length is the same it compares them alphabetically. So if you want to sort items alphabetically delete these lines form `Compare` method in `NodeSorter`:

```cs
 if (tx.Text.Length != ty.Text.Length)
            return tx.Text.Length - ty.Text.Length;
```

Then it will only compare TreeNodes' text using `string.Compare` so they will be sorted alphabetically form a to z.